# How to find the 2nd biggest value in when using a pyspark window?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Consider the pyspark code below, this function will find the maximum of the past 5 values in column "xcol" for each point in time. How can I find the second one? If there are repititive max I want the max to go to new_col, e.g. [ 1 2 3 3 1 ] --> 3

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import * 
df = ...<a datafrme>
a_window= Window.partitionBy("k1","k2").orderBy("time").rowsBetween(-5, 0)
df = df.withColumn( new_col, (max(col("xcol")).over(a_window) ))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can collect your window into a list to then find the its two greatest elements.

Let's start with a sample dataframe:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt 
from random import randint

df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(
        [[i % 3, i % 5, dt.date(2010, 1, (i) % 31 + 1), randint(0, 10)] for i in range(100)], 
        columns=['k1', 'k2', 'time', 'xcol'])) \
    .orderBy('k1', 'k2', 'time')
df.show()
```

We'll use the same window spec as the one your defined:

```py
w = Window.partitionBy("k1","k2").orderBy("time").rowsBetween(-5, 0)
df \
    .withColumn("sequence", psf.sort_array(psf.collect_list(psf.col('xcol')).over(w), asc=False)) \
    .select('*', psf.col("sequence")[0].alias('max1'), psf.col("sequence")[1].alias('max2')) \
    .show()

        +---+---+----------+----+------------------+----+----+
        | k1| k2|      time|xcol|          sequence|max1|max2|
        +---+---+----------+----+------------------+----+----+
        |  1|  3|2010-01-12|   3|               [3]|   3|null|
        |  1|  3|2010-01-13|   3|            [3, 3]|   3|   3|
        |  1|  3|2010-01-14|   9|         [9, 3, 3]|   9|   3|
        |  1|  3|2010-01-27|   7|      [9, 7, 3, 3]|   9|   7|
        |  1|  3|2010-01-28|   2|   [9, 7, 3, 3, 2]|   9|   7|
        |  1|  3|2010-01-29|   0|[9, 7, 3, 3, 2, 0]|   9|   7|
        |  1|  0|2010-01-09|   6|               [6]|   6|null|
        |  1|  0|2010-01-10|   4|            [6, 4]|   6|   4|
        |  1|  0|2010-01-11|   2|         [6, 4, 2]|   6|   4|
        |  1|  0|2010-01-24|   0|      [6, 4, 2, 0]|   6|   4|
        |  1|  0|2010-01-25|   6|   [6, 6, 4, 2, 0]|   6|   6|
        |  1|  0|2010-01-26|   2|[6, 6, 4, 2, 2, 0]|   6|   6|
        |  1|  1|2010-01-01|   9|               [9]|   9|null|
        |  1|  1|2010-01-02|   8|            [9, 8]|   9|   8|
        |  1|  1|2010-01-15|   2|         [9, 8, 2]|   9|   8|
        |  1|  1|2010-01-16|   7|      [9, 8, 7, 2]|   9|   8|
        |  1|  1|2010-01-17|   9|   [9, 9, 8, 7, 2]|   9|   9|
        |  1|  1|2010-01-30|   9|[9, 9, 9, 8, 7, 2]|   9|   9|
        |  1|  1|2010-01-31|   6|[9, 9, 8, 7, 6, 2]|   9|   9|
        |  0|  1|2010-01-04|   1|               [1]|   1|null|
        +---+---+----------+----+------------------+----+----+
```

You can use `collect_set` if you want distinct values